# Getting current location on phone, not working? [Android]

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location, google-play-services

This is so far. It's supposed to display the current location as latitude and longitude in two separate textviews.

I've tried this on the emulator and a real android phone and it doesnt work on either. Nothing happens, the textviews doest display any coordinates. There is no errors either.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL = 60000;
private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_FASTEST = 15000;
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_COARSE_LOCATION = 102;
private TextView latitudeTextView;
private TextView longitudeTextView;
private ImageButton imageButton;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
private double mLatitude;
private double mLongitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    latitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeTextView);
    longitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeTextView);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_FASTEST);
    locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    requestLocationUpdates();
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_COARSE_LOCATION);

        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLatitude));
    longitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLongitude));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(googleApiClient.isConnected())
        requestLocationUpdates();;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
}
```

}

Why does it not work? I followed a few guides, one of them being android developers guide.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Thankful for any input.

Comment: You need to identify which line of code is not working properly by using `Log.d`. Once you find a point where unexpected or no value is obtained then post the question. So put a `Log.d` statement after every line. No point in asking to waste their time without you figuring out what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience the emulator does not work with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`, but requires `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`.

Change the line of code

```
locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

to

```
LocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

I also notice the permissions request dialog box only grants permission for the coarse location. I would change this to the fine location. Change the line of code from:

```
new String[] Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_COARSE_LOCATION);
```

to

```
requestPermissions(new
         String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
         MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
```

and define a string value for `MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION`

Finally, check that location permissions have been granted on the device or emulator. Go to 'settings' -> 'apps' and check that the app is using the location service. If not, click on 'permissions' and turn on the service.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. When posting, please use code formatting markdown when posting code - see the guide http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. Happy hacking!